# How can I read with R data.table a csv with dates

Tags: r, data.table

How can I read perfectly this kind of CSV that has dates, using data.table library?

```
date
2011-12-31T12:00:00Z
2011-12-31T13:00:00Z
2011-12-31T14:00:00Z
2011-12-31T15:00:00Z
2011-12-31T16:00:00Z
2011-12-31T17:00:00Z
2011-12-31T18:00:00Z
2011-12-31T19:00:00Z
```

The issue that I have is that is not recognizing date format:

Warning message in fread: Starting data input on line 2 and discarding line 1 because it has too few or too many items to be column names or data: date

I use to read it:

```
data<-fread(data.csv,header=T)
```

And the data.table returned is:

```
2011-12-31T12   00  00Z
2011-12-31T13   0   00Z
2011-12-31T14   0   00Z
2011-12-31T15   0   00Z
2011-12-31T16   0   00Z
2011-12-31T17   0   00Z
2011-12-31T18   0   00Z
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try updating your installation to the development version of `data.table` (1.10.5+); the `sep` detection logic has improved a bit of late:

```
# if this doesn't work for you, check the Installation page on GitHub
install.packages('data.table', type = 'source',
                 repos = 'http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table')
```

With that your file reads without any other input:

```
fread('date
2011-12-31T12:00:00Z
2011-12-31T13:00:00Z
2011-12-31T14:00:00Z
2011-12-31T15:00:00Z
2011-12-31T16:00:00Z
2011-12-31T17:00:00Z
2011-12-31T18:00:00Z
2011-12-31T19:00:00Z
')
#                    date
# 1: 2011-12-31T12:00:00Z
# 2: 2011-12-31T13:00:00Z
# 3: 2011-12-31T14:00:00Z
# 4: 2011-12-31T15:00:00Z
# 5: 2011-12-31T16:00:00Z
# 6: 2011-12-31T17:00:00Z
# 7: 2011-12-31T18:00:00Z
# 8: 2011-12-31T19:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```
data<-fread("data.csv",sep=",")
```

Comment: `sep = '\n'` is more robust

Comment: Why is more robust?

Comment: `sep = ','` works for your file (as presented, yes), but in a file with potentially millions of lines and hundreds of columns, it's hard to know where whatever `sep` you happen to choose might show up unexpectedly. `sep = '\n'` obviates that.